# Given a triple integral representing the (electric) vector field of a continuous volume charge distribution, how to obtain the potential function?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, line-integrals, electromagnetism

My question is about the math involved in the concept of electric potential. Though this is a physics concept, it is basically a lot of vector calculus. The derivations below are based on the content of Ch. 2 in Griffiths' *Electrodynamics*.

I'm going to write quite a few steps in reasoning and the concept of electric field and electric potential before getting to the actual question. **My question actually starts at the bold text below.**

Electric potential is defined as

$$V(\vec{r})=-\int_{\vec{r}_0}^{\vec{r}} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{r}\tag{1}$$

where $\vec{E}$ is an (electric) vector field. We are interested in finding this field.

If we knew $V$ then we could find $E$ by taking the gradient of $V$.

Typically, we know a charge density $\rho(\vec{r})$ (and in this example I am assuming the density is per volume) for a continuous charge.

Now, if our charge were a point charge at the origin of our coordinate system, the electric field at some point $\vec{r}$ would be

$$\vec{E}=k_e\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{r}\tag{2}$$

and the electric potential at that point (using $vec{r}_0=\vec{r}_\infty$; that is, some point with infinite radius; not sure exactly how to write this vector correctly) is

$$V(\vec{r})=-\int_{\vec{r}_\infty}^{\vec{r}} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{r}\tag{3}$$

$$=-\int_{\vec{r}_\infty}^{\vec{r}} k_e\frac{q}{r^2}\hat{r}\cdot (dr\hat{r}+rd\theta\hat{\theta}+r\sin{\theta}d\phi d\theta)\tag{4}$$

$$=-\int_{\infty}^r k_e\frac{q}{r^2}dr\tag{5}$$

$$=k_e\frac{q}{r}\tag{6}$$

Now, in geneal the point charge could be located at a position $\vec{r}_s$ instead of the origin, and so we would have

$$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=k_e\frac{q}{\lVert \vec{r}-\vec{r}_s\rVert^2}\frac{\vec{r}-\vec{r}_s}{\lVert \vec{r}-\vec{r}_s\rVert}\tag{7}$$

$$=k_e\frac{q}{\eta^2}\hat{\eta}\tag{8}$$

Note that $\vec{\eta}$ is the separation vector between the positions of field point and source charge.

Now, the book I am reading proceeds to say that the potential in this case is

$$V(\vec{r})=k_e\frac{q}{\eta}\tag{9}$$

(I am not sure how to show this exactly, [and have asked how in a separate question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/762008/how-do-we-find-the-expression-for-potential-of-the-electric-field-of-a-source-po))

But moving on, if we accept that (9) is true, then because of superposition we have that for $n$ discrete charges

$$V(\vec{r})=k_e\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{q_i}{\eta_i}\tag{10}$$

and if we have a continuous distribution then

$$V(\vec{r})=k_e\int\frac{1}{\eta}dq\tag{11}$$

If the continuous distribution of charge is a volume charge, then

$$V(\vec{r})=k_e\iiint_V\frac{\rho(\vec{r_s})}{\eta}d\tau\tag{12}$$

The path to finding (12) above seems to be that you compute the electric potential generated by each infinitesimal charge $dq$ on the charged volume, and then use superposition principle to add the potentials up, which is an integral over the volume.

That is, if we think about the volume as a bunch of tiny charges $dq$ then Iwe have

$$d\vec{E}(\vec{r})=k_e\frac{dq}{\eta^2}\hat{\eta}\tag{15}$$

where $\vec{\eta}=\vec{r}-\vec{r}_{dq}$

and the potential at $\vec{r}$ due to this electric field is

$$V_{dq}(\vec{r})=k_e\frac{dq}{\eta}\tag{16}$$

$$=k_e\frac{\rho(\vec{r}_{dq})d\tau}{\eta}\tag{17}$$

And so if we sum all of these up over our volume, we are integrating over the volume of charge, and so we get (12).

**My question is how to obtain (12) by first calculating the total electric field at $\vec{r}$ and then integrating to get the electric potential.**

For a charged volume with charge density per unit volume $\rho(\vec{r_s})$ we have

$$\vec{E}(\vec{r})=\iiint_V k_e\frac{\rho(\vec{r}_s)d\tau}{\eta^2}\vec{\eta}\tag{13}$$

$$V(\vec{r})=\int_{\vec{r}_\infty}^{\vec{r}} \vec{E}(\vec{r})\cdot d\vec{r}\tag{14}$$

Is there a way to go from (13) to (12) by subbing in (13) into (14)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We begin with the expression for the electric field

$$\vec E(\vec r')=k_e\int_{V}\frac{\rho(\vec r_s)(\vec r'-\vec r_s)}{|\vec r'-\vec r_s|^3}\,dV_s\tag1$$

Now, if we integrate $(1)$ from $\vec r_1$ to $\vec r$, and let $|\vec r_1|\to \infty$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
-\lim_{|\vec r_1|\to \infty}\int_{\vec r_1}^{\vec r}\vec E(\vec r')\cdot d\vec r'&=-\lim_{|\vec r_1|\to \infty}\int_{\vec r_1}^{\vec r}\left(k_e\int_{V}\frac{\rho(\vec r_s)(\vec r'-\vec r_s)}{|\vec r'-\vec r_s|^3}\,dV_s\right)\cdot d\vec r'\\\\
&=-\lim_{|\vec r_1|\to \infty}\int_{\vec r_1}^{\vec r}\left(-k_e\int_{V}\rho(\vec r_s)\nabla '\frac{1}{|\vec r'-\vec r_s|}\,dV_s\right)\cdot d\vec r'\\\\
&=k_e \lim_{|\vec r_1|\to \infty}\int_{V} \rho(\vec r_s)\int_{\vec r_1}^{\vec r}\nabla '\frac{1}{|\vec r'-\vec r_s|}\cdot d\vec r'\,dV_s\\\\
&=k_e \lim_{|\vec r_1|\to \infty}\int_{V} \rho(\vec r_s)\left(\frac1{|\vec r-\vec r_s|}-\frac1{|\vec r_1-\vec r_s|}\right)\,dV_s\\\\
&=k_e \int_{V} \frac{\rho(\vec r_s)}{|\vec r-\vec r_s|}\,dV_s
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Just so OP is aware: one has to invoke Fubini’s theorem in the third step, but this is something every physics text takes for granted.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, most physics texts don't justify such operator interchanges.  There ia a branch of physics, mathematical physics, where rigor is central.